# Why is this bootstrap column going outside the container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, templates

I'm building my first template with Bootstrap and I'm having trouble with a div going outside the container. In the code below, the `col-sm-2` is on the left side outside the borders of the container ([working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gn4Luxoc/)).

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row property-ad">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                an image is going here
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                and some describing text here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="right-side-ad">
            some advertisement is going here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.navbar` doesn't have negative margins while `.row` does

Comment: The col isn't outside is inside the row ... you can put the navbar outside the container or just inside a row element http://www.bootply.com/GOjm65w13i

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gn4Luxoc/2/

Comment: @Danko - Thanks for that bootply, but in there the right yellow box now doesn't align with the menu on the top. Any ideas how I can fix that?

Comment: Just don't use another div inside the col http://www.bootply.com/FFGq41Ppox ... also you don't need that nested columns inside the first eight

Comment: @kramer65 id doesn't align because you are using `.property-ad` class together with the `.row` class. If you add `.row` class to `.right-side-ad` you will see the same misalignment on the right side